# Is it possible to use static linking when wrapping fortran code with f2py?

Tags: python, fortran, gfortran, f2py

As I discussed in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65407175/how-to-install-python-on-a-server-without-root-privileges), I am trying to run a python script that uses f2py wrapped Fortran code on a remote server. If I compile the f2py module locally on my own pc and then run the script on the server, I get the following error,

> ImportError: liblapack.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This is logical since lapack and blas are both not installed on the remote server, and sadly I do not have the root privileges to install them. I am wondering if I could fix this by using static linking. On the GNU [wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranGettingStarted) it is stated that,

> One way to avoid this (more ideas can be found on the binaries page) is to use the so-called "static linking", available with option `-static`. Gfortran then puts the library code inside the program created, thus enabling it to run without the library present (like, on a computer where gfortran is not installed).

This sounds like exactly what I would need. If the required library files are included in the f2py module then I won't need the lapack and blas modules on the remote server and I can just run it as is. However I am not sure that this static linking actually works with f2py. Currently I run,

```
python -m numpy.f2py -llapack -lblas -c --fcompiler=gnu95 --compiler=unix signature_file.pyf 
object_files.o
```

`object_files.o` means all interdependent Fortran files compiled into object files, i.e. I ran

```
gfortran -c -llapack -lblas object_file.F90
```

on all relevant files. Now I would like to do this with static linking, but how? I have tried adding -static when compiling the object files, but this didn't change anything. I have also tried adding -static to the f2py call, but this just gives an unknown option error.

Comment: *and sadly I do not have the root privileges to install them*: Not a problem, install the DLLs in a directory that you add to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Regarding the static linking, it should be possible, but note that f2py builds a dynamic library anyway. However, I believe you can link a static version of blas/lapack to build this dll (maybe by forcing the correct `liblapack.a` file instead of just `-llapack`? -- if the static libs are installed on your local machine, by the way)

Comment: Can't you just copy  liblapack.so.3 and any dependencies to the remote server, set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to where you've copied it and run?  Use ldd on liblapack.so.3 to find out what else it is picking up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible inside a `setup.py` script if you use `Extension` from `numpy.distutils.core` with `extra_link_args=["-static", "-static-libgfortran", "-static-libgcc"]`.

It is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49765622/8028981).